# Removing date from the filename

Tags: linux

I am working on a tool which accepts linux commands. 
I have files coming from differnt sources and i want to remove date from the file and tool supports '%F' i.e. absolute file name only.

**%F is** `/Dir1/Subdir/ABC_20190101_PQR.csv` 
**What I want is** `/Dir1/Subdir/ABC_PQR.csv`

kindly help.

I tried some commands but none worked

I want /Dir1/Subdir/ABC_PQR.csv

```
mv %F {%F//_{0-9}//_{}}
```

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: What is this tool that supports '%F'?  It's tough to suggest syntax for an unspecified tool.  Check its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this OK?

```
echo ${text} | sed -r 's/(.*)(_[[:digit:]]*_)(.*)/\1_\3/'
```

**Example:**

```
text="/Dir1/Subdir/ABC_20190101_PQR.csv"
echo ${text} | sed -r 's/(.*)(_[[:digit:]]*_)(.*)/\1_\3/'
/Dir1/Subdir/ABC_PQR.csv
```

This uses BASH.

Comment: `sed -E` is more portable that `sed -r` .   (eg, it will work on non gnu-sed, common in macos)

Comment: Same: `sed -E 's/_[[:digit:]]{8}_/_/'`